# Regex to capture version in two different schemes

Tags: regex

So, I have a regex that is supposed to pull out the version from a given path. The problem is that the path changed recently and now I need a regex to handle both cases. However, the or logic I tried adding doesn't work. Here are the two schemes:

```
/a/b/c/version/foo-bar_otherversion-version-assembly.jar
```

and

```
/a/b/version/foo/foo-bar_otherversion-assembly.jar
```

and these regexes are what I've tried:

```
^.*\/(.*)(\/foo|\/)\/foo-bar[^\/]*\.jar$
^.*\/(.*)\/(foo|)(\/)?foo-bar[^\/]*\.jar$
```

The second one parses well enough, but puts foo in the version slot.

Requirement: The code will read the first capture as the version.

Note that the change is the addition of foo after version - to be explicit

Comment: Yeah, what is the output you are looking for.

Comment: Well, try [`^.*?\/([^\/]*)\/(?:foo\/)?foo-bar[^\/]*\.jar$`](https://regex101.com/r/5Lj5i7/1)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I spread the full requirements out too much. I need to be able to extract the version from both of the above strings. It's basically a bintray path and I need to pull out the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
^.*?\/([^\/]*)\/(?:foo\/)?foo-bar[^\/]*\.jar$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Lj5i7/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `.*?\/` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to and including a `/`
- `([^\/]*)` - Group 1: 0+ chars other than `/`
- `\/` - a `/`
- `(?:foo\/)?` - an optional `foo/` substring
- `foo-bar` - a literal substring
- `[^\/]*` - any 0+ chars other than `/`
- `\.jar` - a `.jar` substring
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Great! I especially like the write up. I was not aware of the ?: for a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

The second expression with some modifications will work:

```
(?:/.*\/.\/)(.*?)(?:/foo)(?:/|-)(?:.*$)
```

The primary reason why its capturing foo in orignal version is because you are not assigning it to a non capturing group.

[online regex](https://regex101.com/r/QpGaYM/5)

Comment: This does not work for the first string. It extracts the path before version.

Comment: Interesting that that link allows non escaped slashes...that works now if I escape the slashes

Comment: @JustinPihony there are some variations in this with each language, broadly its quite similar e.g. you can make an if else then kinda regex fir php but nothing like that in others (or at least in the simple strucutre )